# a word for "getting many processes done in one place"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In my contract management system, I want to update the electricity usage for each contract. I can either enter this information manually in each contract by opening it, entering the information, then saving, or use a feature that can import information (in an Excel sheet, for example) and distribute it to each relevant contract.

What can I call this feature? The developers called it "consolidation", which is clearly the wrong word, because I'm not combining the values. The values remain and are linked to the relevant contracts.

In a sentence I would describe this as importing electricity usage in bulk. But is there a good single word for this act of combining individual small processes into one collective process?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about looking at electricity use for all contracts combined, the developers are using a correct term for what you are talking about.

Depending on context, [consolidation](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/consolidation) can mean

> The action or process of combining a number of things into a single more effective or coherent whole

Another word for this can be [collation](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/collation).

If you are talking about inputting electricity use for budgeting purposes for example and allocating to each contract by percentage, then you would be talking about **percentage distribution**

If you are talking about financial costs of each contract then you would be talking about [reconciliation](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reconciliation).

### --Edit after OP edit--

Using something like Excel to collect all electricity usage would be a process of consolidation by collating the figures (manually or automatically) into one spreadsheet and each figure in that spreadsheet would help to reconcile a balance sheet of all contract costs.